# Firefox - Why is scroll button opening the last closed tab?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-tabs, scroll-wheel

Prior to reformatting, when I scroll-clicked the title bar outside of current tabs, a new tab would be spawned and I'd be brought to my new tab page. After reformatting, this functionality has changed, albeit marginally. When I scroll-click the title bar but outside of current tabs, the last tab I closed is re-opened unless there are no closed tabs, in which case it does what I want it to - open a new tab.

Does anybody know why this is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Check whether a related setting titled `browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick` is set to true in about:config.

Comment: It is indeed set to true.

Comment: Yeah, it's more to do with opening links in new tabs when middle-clicked, but I couldn't find anything specifically title bar related. Which version of Firefox are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Firefox is 37.0.2 and Windows 7 SP1. I should specify, I have my tabs in the titlebar, the same bar where minimize/maximize/close buttons exist. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I have it set up the same way but I don't know why it isn't working for you. I installed Firefox recently for someone on their new system and out of the box this feature worked the same as it always has. Have you tried disabling all add-ons? Perhaps one of them is to blame.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, so I tried it and the functionality remained the same.